# WebApp doesn't recognize that an input field was changed when set with jQuery in PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, phantomjs, jquery-events, html-input

I open [telegram](https://web.telegram.org/#/) with PhantomJS and try to fill phone number input with evaluate page like below:

```
page.evaluate(function(){
    $("input[name='phone_number']").val("123456789");
});
```

When PhantomJS clicks on next button with jQuery the alert massage says:

> "tel input is empty"

but when the page is rendered we can see numbers in the input field. How can I fill this input?

Comment: not it's not problem , jquery code works , but web app dont read value attr of element ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is probably that the web app has some event listeners on that field, but they are not called when you change the value directly. You can try to trigger some of those events with jQuery.

For example:

```
$("input[name='phone_number']").blur();
```

or

```
$("input[name='phone_number']").change();
```

I found that this doesn't necessarily work. You can try to use the native keypress events in PhantomJS like this:

```
page.evaluate(function() {
    document.querySelector("input[name='phone_number']").focus();
});
page.sendEvent("keypress", "123456789");
```

[`page.sendEvent()`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html) sends the given keys to the focussed input field. That's why you need to focus to the intended field beforehand.